# Connecting to MSSQL from Doctrine/Symfony2

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Express 2016 from Doctrine in Symfony 2. I am using IIS server. Currently, this is what I have in my parameters.yaml:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
    database_host: localhost\SQLExpress16
    database_port: 1433
    database_name: EvolutionWebShop
    database_user: sa
    database_password: **PASS**
```

But when I try to run the command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` I get the error message:

`SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I've made sure that my firewall isn't blocking port 1433, and that my SQL Server instance is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[image: TCP/IP Settings]

I've also run the following test script, just to make sure that I can definitely connect from PHP:

```
<?php
try{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=localhost\\SQLExpress16; Database=WebShopTest", "sa", "**PASS**");  
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 

}
print "Success";
?>
```

The docs do mention Microsoft SQL, but I can't find any specific examples. Has anyone managed to get this working?

> This chapter is all about the Doctrine ORM, which aims to let you map
>   objects to a relational database (such as MySQL, PostgreSQL or
>   Microsoft SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with your architecture, somehow it works on 32 bits but does not in 64. Although odbc 11 is supposed to be able to create datasources of 32 bits. Maybe something along the way is looking for specifically the 32 bit version to take the request and pass it along but it does not find it?

I still have that problem and am looking for an answer, but the quickest way out of it is just go for 32 bit everything.